# Is there a way to not include the {{ content }} variable in a node template and still have the node cache clear when the node is updated?

Tags: caching

We have nodes that have dozens of fields and have elected to not include the {{ content }} variable as it is tedious and looks messy having something like the following just to **not** print the fields. We're manually outputting each field as needed like {{ content.myfield }}.

The problem is that when the {{ content }} variable is not in a template then that node's cache does not get cleared when a user modifies the node's content and they have to contact and admin to clear the Drupal caches.

Surely there must be a way to have a node's cache cleared when it is updated and its theme template does not have the {{ content }} variable. Please help.

```
{{ content|without('field_blog_posts','field_breadcumb_t','field_call_to_action','field_call_to_actions_title','field_customer_support_body','field_customer_support_button_te','field_customer_support_image','field_customer_support_title','field_hero_body','field_solutions_hero_image','field_hero_link_1','field_hero_link_2','field_hero_title','field_learn_more_text','field_meta_tags','field_newsletter_signup_banner','field_newsletter_signup_banner_m','field_product_spotlight_title','field_read_more_link_text','field_section_one_category_1','field_section_one_category_2','field_section_one_sub_title','field_section_one_title','field_section_one_video','field_section_two_category_1','field_section_two_category_2','field_section_two_sub_title','field_section_two_title','field_section_twovideo','field_section_two_view_all_link','field_spotlighted_product') }}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply render it into a variable and just do nothing with it:

```
{# rendering the content into a variable doesn't visibly render anything, but forces the cache to bubble up #}
{% set dummy = content|render %}
```

Answer (score 6):

Install the [twig tweak module](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) (v3.x) and then use [`cache_metadata`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/twig_tweak/-/blob/3.x/docs/cheat-sheet.md#cache-metadata) filter.

> When using raw values from entities or render arrays it is essential to
> ensure that cache metadata are bubbled up.

```
{# Ensure content cache metadata is rendered for the display as a whole. #}
{{ content|cache_metadata }}
```